# width doesnt change in a media query rest of the properties change

Tags: css, media-queries

At first the *container* is given a `width` of  *80%* and when this is changed with a `media query` for a `width` of *992px* it does not change but when the `background-color` is specified for the same media query it changes.
JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q4hqq2ro/

---

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <h1 > <span class="light">Spirituality</span> Forums</h1>
            <div class="register user">Register</div>
            <div class="login user">Login</div>
            <span class="close">X</span>
            <div class="search-icon"><a href=""></a></div>
            <input type="search" class="search">
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </header>

        <div class="advertisment">
        </div>
        </div> <!-- container -->
```

---

CSS

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne);

    body{
        background: #e6e3d7;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    /*-----------------Header----------------------*/


    .container{
        max-width: 80%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    header{
        background-color: #b47941;
        padding-left: 1%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }

    .logo{
        background: url("images/small.jpg") no-repeat;
        width: 150px;
        height:90px;
        float: left;
    }

    header h1 {
        display: inline-block;
        font:200% cursive ;
        color: white;
        line-height: 90px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        color: #daccb7;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .light{
        color: #f5f3ea;
    }

    .clear{
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    /*---------------register-------------*/

    .register{
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 2%;
    }

    .user{
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 62px;
        background: #e6e3d7;
        width:10%;
        font: 100%/160% arial;
        text-align: center;
        color: #a35800;
        line-height: 187%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /*---------------search-------------*/
    .search{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 64px;
        right: 30%;
        width: 18%;
        height: 26px;
    }

    .close{
        color: grey;
        position: absolute;
        top: 68px;
        right: 30%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #e6e3d7;
        width: 2%;
    }

    input[type="search"]{
        border: 0;
        color: #a35800;
        background: #e6e3d7;
        padding: .5%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .search-icon{
        background:url("images/search.gif") no-repeat;
        width:32px;
        height:23px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-top: 66.5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /*-----------advertisment------------*/

    .advertisment{
        height: 320px;
    }

    /*-----------Media Queries----------*/

     @media (max-width : 992px) {

        .container {
            width: 90%;
            background: green;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please specify on which resolution u have checked. If you are the checking the jsfiddle, media query will take width of the iframe to do the responsiveness. So I have changed media query @media (max-width : 700px)  and checked.. It is working fine [link](https://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/2gm3r2zp/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Because your old code is not gets Replaced by new Code

use !important with your new Code

```
.container{
    max-width: 80% !important;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid instructing `!important` usage and guide users to increase rule [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I think its better to use `!important` When we have to Replace our lot of code to just change a single element .. @emmanuel

Comment: No it isn't. `!important` cannot get overridden without another `!important` usage so you will end up with a stylesheet that won't be easily maintained. You have to read [The !important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you set before:

```
.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

And the media query does not override that. I tested your code, replace either the max-width with just width on the previous line, or use max-width: 90% on the media query. That would do the trick.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`width` and `max-width` are different properties. If you want to deactivate `max-width` you have to override it to it's initial value of `none` so `width` will be the only property that will affect element's width.

```
.container {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Reference: [MDN - max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

Answer (score 0):

you can use max-width in place of width ,it will work.
in media query width is the only properties that affect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).